# How to use @MappedSuperClass as @OneToMany mapping collection in JPA Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, spring-data-jpa, entity

I am using Entity Inheritance for the first time and stuck with using a MappedSuperClass as collection inside another MappedSuperClass.

I have two similar set of Entities which must save data to different tables in DB. But since the business logic is perfectly same, so I want to use base classes for these entities, so these base classes can be used in common JPA repository (@NoRepositoryBean).

```
@MappedSuperClass
class Classroom {

    String std;
}

@MappedSuperClass
class School {

    String name;

    @OneToMany //ERROR
    Set<Classroom> rooms; 
}

@entity
@table("A_SCHOOL")
class ASchool extends School {

    Set<AClassroom> rooms; 
}

@entity
@table("A_CLASSROOM")
class AClassroom extends Classroom {

}

@entity
@table("B_SCHOOL")
class BSchool extends School {

    Set<BClassroom> rooms; 
}

@entity
@table("B_CLASSROOM")
class BClassroom extends Classroom {

}
```

The issue is the @OneToMany mapping in `School` is not allowed since `Classroom` is not an entity.
Considering the common JPA repository (and all other business logic) is designed to work with only School/Classroom, how should I update the association of Classrooms in School?

Answer (score 1):

the idea of using `@MappedSuperClass` is to make common attributes between different classes in one place .

in your case each `School` has dependency on certain `ClassRoom` so you need to declare that relationship in each subclass of school,
so you need to remove the relationship from the parent class and declare it in all `School` subclasses .

have a look at this tutorial :[How to inherit properties from a base class entity using @MappedSuperclass with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-inherit-properties-from-a-base-class-entity-using-mappedsuperclass-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)